# To store the value of the check box and radio button in the database ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails generate scaffold Post title:string body:text category_id:integer status_id:integer

generated the scaffold like this. `category_id` and `status_id` is used for check-box and radio button

Here the value are stored as a integer values like category 1 or 2 but i need to store the value of the category like tv or mobile in the database because we can not understand what product is required .

thank you in advance

<%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  
  
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  
  
    <%= f.label :category_id %>
    <%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, @post.category_id) %>
  
  
    <%= f.label :status_id %>
     <%= collection_radio_buttons(:post, :status_id, Status.all, :id, :name) %>
  
  
    <%= f.submit %>

[link is here i followed those steps](http://buildingrails.com/a/rails_forms_for_beginners)

Comment: have you given the relation between post ,category and post , status???

Comment: well upload your models.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store the text value because it already in the `Category` table.

if you want to know what product is, you can use `@product.category.try(:name)` if associations setup correctly